# warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, mingw, warnings

I am trying to understand why my compiler is warning me about this code:

```
static const char *const  _menuMain_Strings_1[] __ATTR_PROGMEM__ = { _menuMain_L1,
        _menuMain_L2, _menuMain_L3, _menuMain_L4 }

static const MENU_DEFINITION _menuDef_Main_1 __ATTR_PROGMEM__ = {
        _menuMain_Strings_1, _menuMain_Fields_1 };
```

```
../menudefs.h:53:3: warning: initialization discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   53 |   _menuMain_Strings_1, _menuMain_Fields_1 };
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

At first, I had to add the extra ***const** in order for it to generate a hex file to remove the compiler error. From my assumption, the compiler is discarding one of the **const** regardless. How can I satisfy the compiler without it giving me warnings? Thank you.

Comment: How is `MENU_DEFINITION` defined?  What about `_menuMain_L1`, `_menuMain_L2`, etc?

Comment: You are missing too much code. All I get are compile errors attempting to compile your code. `static const char *const  _menuMain_Strings_1[] = { "a", "bb", "ccc", "dddd" };` compiles just fine with `-Wall`. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that `_menuMain_Strings_1` identifies a pointer to `const` data (which it does), but you are using it to initialize a pointer to non-`const` data.  You have not presented all the details of those types, but this is not about the compiler discarding qualifiers.  Rather, it is about *your code* having a `const`-qualification mismatch.

Such a situation warrants a warning because if the pointed-to data is in fact itself declared `const` (as opposed to that qualification being only in the pointer) then attempting to modify it produces undefined behavior.  The compiler can spot that and reject it when access is through the original, `const`-qualified pointer, but not when access is through the non-`const`-qualifed copy with which `_menuDef_Main_1` is initialized.

> How can I satisfy the compiler without it giving me warnings?

Use `const` consistently or not at all.  And note that it is viral: you can apply `const`-qualification freely, but you cannot safely remove it.  Presumably, you will need to modify the definition of `MENU_DEFINITION` to carry through `const` appropriately, and this may require you to make further changes as a result.